# Replacing old OS will format entire hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, windows, windows-7, hard-drive

I am new to Ubuntu. My laptop is currently running Windows 7 with C, D partition as virtual disks.

Now, I want to have a laptop that runs clean and fresh Ubuntu, and nothing else. All old system data, personal data, viruses, trojan should be completely removed and no partition virtual disks (Disk C, Disk D like in Windows). In an other word, my laptop should get started over again like a newly bought one.

I guess "**[Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu](https://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/latest/u/img/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop/image-installdesktoplongtermsupport-4.jpg)**" option may help. But I am not sure if it will help to format and reset my hard disk OR it will just delete old Windows in C drive and leave other data existed in D drive?

Please advice me. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> It will just delete old Windows in C drive and leave other data existed in D drive?

It will delete all Windows partitions. The partitioner will assume that all NTFS disks belong to Windows and delete it. It will then create 1 big disk to install Ubuntu. If you do not want this and want the partitions to be split into / and /home/ or /, /home/, /datapartition/

- Use the "something else" option.
- Delete all the partitions so you have one big block of "unallocated space". This will delete all Windows data.
- Create new partitions to your liking. In general 25 Gb for a / partition should be enough unless you want to use servers like Apache or MySQL.
- Allocate a few Gb to a swap area. What the ideal amount is depends on your memory; have a look around AU for some topics about this. [What swapfile size to make? I have 4GB RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516996/what-swapfile-size-to-make-i-have-4gb-ram) and [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap)
- Dedicate the remainder to /home/ or a part of it to /home/ and the remainder to a personal partition with a label you set it up with.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I won't need "Something else" option. I just need one single partition. My concern is how I can easy every bit old data on my hard drive so I can start to install a fresh and clean system on my laptop.